# Update Access database with join from another table

Tags: sql, ms-access, join

I have a table in my (Access 2000) DB that I'm looking to update with values from a column in another unlinked table. The main table has columns "company" and "account manager", and the second table has columns "client" and "account manager"...I want to update the account manager values in the main table to the values in the second, based on the "client/company" names. The only problem is that the "client" and "company" values are somewhat mismatched in the tables, for instance there's "XYZ Corp" in the main table vs "XYZ Corp Inc" in the second.

For some reason when I used the wildcard char to get past these minor differences, my update statement doesn't capture any rows to update, I'm sure it's something small but am nevertheless stumped. Here is the statement:

```
UPDATE Main Table 
INNER JOIN Second Table ON Main Table.Company=Second Table.Client 
SET Main Table.AccountManager = Second Table.AccountManager
WHERE Main Table.Company Like 'Second Table.Client' + '*' ;
```

I tried switching around the ordering in the where and set clauses, and in the join statement with no luck. I also tested a full join which Access didn't like. Any suggestions appreciated!

Comment: Are you sure it's not reading Second Table.Client as a char?

Comment: Not sure, should it not be enclosed in single quotes? I'm fairly new to SQL in general obviously!

Comment: It should not, you are saying, with that find Main Table.Company like 'Second Table.Client*'

Comment: Also, you should encase second table and main table like so: [Main Table], [Second Table]